3rd party code and SDKs information for Google play store submission
I am being asked for additional information after submitting my app to the Google Play Store.
This is the relevant part of the form:
The User Data policy states that developers must ensure that any 3rd party code or SDKs added to their apps are compliant with Google Play Developer Program policies. Additionally, developers on Google Play must only collect user data when necessary.
What SDKs does your app use and why? *
Explain how you ensure that any 3rd party code and SDKs used in your app comply with our policies. *
What exactly should I specify for these two questions?
I am using flutter to develop the app is this mean all ui, state management libraries etc.
I am being asked for additional information after submitting my app to the Google Play Store.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
